# 'For' loop for analyzing CheckBoxes in a panel

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, for-loop, checkbox

I have to analyze if the CheckBoxes are checked or not. There are 10 CBs in a TabPage, and they are named in order (cb1, cb2, cb3.. etc.).

```
 For Each c As CheckBox In TabPage4.Controls
        If c.Checked Then
            hello = hello + 1
        End If
    Next
```

I have tried the above but it gives me an unhandled exception error.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in WindowsApplication2.exe 
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'.
```

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: @nhgrif Here it is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in WindowsApplication2.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to @Plutonix code and got it work. Here's the code:

```
Dim n As Integer = 1
For Each c As Control In TabPage4.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is CheckBox Then
            CBs(n) = c
            If CBs(n).Checked Then
                hello = hello + 1
            End If
        End If
        n = n + 1
    Next
```

The Cbs(n) is an array of CheckBoxes I created on a module. It declares the 'c' CheckBox as a Cbs(n) and analyzes that. Then it adds 1 to the variable n and restarts the process until there are no more CheckBoxes left in the TabPage.

Answer (score 1):

since there can be other controls on the page you need to see if each is a check:

```
For Each c As Control In TabPage4.Controls
    if Typeof c is CheckBox then
        if Ctype(c, Checkbox).Checked Then
            hello +=1
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Depending on your VS version, this may work (requires LINQ):

```
For Each c As CheckBox In TabPage4.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
     If c.Checked Then
        hello += 1                ' looks dubious
    End If
Next
```

**Edit**

I am guessing you had something wrong with the `Ctype` portion because all your array does is basically convert the Ctl to a Check (what CType does) but in a more expensive manner.  IF you dont like Ctype (and cant use the second way):

```
Dim chk As CheckBox
For Each c As Control In TabPage4.Controls
    if Typeof c is CheckBox then
        chk  =  Ctype(c, Checkbox)
        if chk.Checked Then
            hello +=1
        End If
    End If
Next
```

No array, no extra object references.

Comment: The program works fine but it does not change the value of hello.

Comment: what is `hello` a string, integer...?  Are there in fact any checkboxes checked?  you could set a breakpoint on `IF...` and see what is going wrong, like is it detecting checkboxes.  update your post with to include `hello` and the loop you are using

Comment: hello is an integer. And yes, the CheckBoxes are checked. I made some changes to your code and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be necessary in this case, but sometimes you need to get them "in order".  Here's an example:

```
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    Dim hello As Integer
    Dim matches() As Control
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        matches = Me.Controls.Find("cb" & i, True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is CheckBox Then
            cb = DirectCast(matches(0), CheckBox)
            If cb.Checked Then
                hello = hello + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
```